How can we prevent Roku sleep timeout inside App?
I am trying to prevent Roku sleep timeout inside the app.
Is it possible to prevent the Roku sleep timeout when I play Steaming inside my app?
Can anyone suggest any way to achieve this?
Edited
I am looking to continue streaming.
Currently, when I play any channel on my Roku, it sometimes automatically displays Roku Roku(with an up-and-down motion).
Can I control this inside the App?
When I see some apps, it's not coming, and some apps, it's coming.
I need to know how can i disabled.

If you're trying to suppress the screensaver during playback you can use disableScreenSaver interface of the Video node.
Roku SDK says:

Set this to true to suppress the screensaver. This is typically used
to suppress the screensaver when playing audio-only streams.

Reference to docs
The animation you described is called screensaver. It's used to optimize energy consumption and save screen. It can be disabled by user in Roku Settings, or limited by developer for specific nodes only(e.g Video).
One more option is using your channel screensaver.

Thank you for your great reply. I edited my question. I am looking for remove the screen saver while steaming in app. currently when i not performing any action then it coming randomly
